# Paypal curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS with PHP variables

Tags: php, curl, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

Morning

Having a go at adding a custom PayPal Subscription to my website using PHP and the PayPal API. I have not really used PHP, or Curl before so its taking a while but I have managed to write a script to get an access token from the sandbox and link to an existing subscription plan which you you can subscribe to. The code below works...

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "\n  {\n   \"plan_id\":$planID,\n   \"start_time\":$startTime,\n      \"application_context\": {\n        \"brand_name\": \"Sleep Happy Mattress\",\n        \"locale\": \"en-US\",\n        \"shipping_preference\": \"SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS\",\n        \"user_action\": \"SUBSCRIBE_NOW\",\n        \"payment_method\": {\n          \"payer_selected\": \"PAYPAL\",\n          \"payee_preferred\": \"IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED\"\n        },\n        \"return_url\": \"https://example.com/returnUrl\",\n        \"cancel_url\": \"https://example.com/cancelUrl\"\n      }\n    }");
```

However whenever I try to include the planID and start_time as php variables within curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS I get a "Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema." error.

```
$planID = 'P-25Y56437062492726MFWZ4GI';
$startTime = '2021-10-22T00:00:00Z';
```

// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "\n  {\n   \"plan_id\": \"P-25Y56437062492726MFWZ4GI\",\n   \"start_time\": \"2021-10-22T00:00:00Z\",\n      \"application_context\": {\n        \"brand_name\": \"Sleep Happy Mattress\",\n        \"locale\": \"en-UK\",\n        \"shipping_preference\": \"SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS\",\n        \"user_action\": \"SUBSCRIBE_NOW\",\n        \"payment_method\": {\n          \"payer_selected\": \"PAYPAL\",\n          \"payee_preferred\": \"IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED\"\n        },\n        \"return_url\": \"https://example.com/returnUrl\",\n        \"cancel_url\": \"https://example.com/cancelUrl\"\n      }\n    }");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "\n  {\n   \"plan_id\":$planID,\n   \"start_time\":$startTime,\n      \"application_context\": {\n        \"brand_name\": \"Sleep Happy Mattress\",\n        \"locale\": \"en-US\",\n        \"shipping_preference\": \"SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS\",\n        \"user_action\": \"SUBSCRIBE_NOW\",\n        \"payment_method\": {\n          \"payer_selected\": \"PAYPAL\",\n          \"payee_preferred\": \"IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED\"\n        },\n        \"return_url\": \"https://example.com/returnUrl\",\n        \"cancel_url\": \"https://example.com/cancelUrl\"\n      }\n    }");
```

Is my concatenation wrong or do the variables need manipulating in someway first, or both??

Many thanks for the help

Chris

Comment: Can't you just use `json_encode()` instead of using plain-text JSON?

Comment: And store in variable then use ...(CURL_POSTFIELDS, $datas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your JSON string like this:

```php
$data = [
    'plan_id' => $planID,
    'start_time' => $startTime,
    'application_context' => [
        'brand_name' => 'Sleep Happy Mattress',
        'locale' => 'en-US',
        'shipping_preference' => 'SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS',
        'user_action' => 'SUBSCRIBE_NOW',
        'payment_method' => [
            'payer_selected' => 'PAYPAL',
            'payee_preferred' => 'IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED'
        ],
        'return_url' => 'https://example.com/returnUrl',
        'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancelUrl'
    ],    
];
```

Then you can check that the nesting etc is correct  (please note I don't know if the above is correct, I just copied it from your question), and if you  `json_encode` it you will create well-formed JSON.

```php
$jsonEncoded = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Many thanks I will give using an array ago if its better practice - if i mess it up @Preston PHX has corrected my poorly constructed  JSON string!

Answer (score 0):

Do not specify nor include a `start_time`, unless you want problems with amounts not showing in checkout.

Your problem is you did not keep quotes around the variable values, which is necessary for JSON string syntax. Observe:

```
\"plan_id\": \"$planID\",
```

---

Using json_encode() to construct your string from an array object would be better.

Comment: Many thanks.... I wondered about the inclusion of quotes and did experiment but couldnt get it correct.  I need a start_time as i want the subscription to start form a customer defined date rather than immediately. If didn't need this feature i could have saved myself a lot of hassle and have used PayPal buttons. I will try constructing an array if its better practice.

Comment: It would be simple to add a start_time in a JS button `createSubscription`, if you really need one

Comment: Arr that would be very useful..... I did try the other week with this as a guess as couldn't find any documentation about adding parameters to createSubscription other than a customID

createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
    
return actions.subscription.create({
      
'plan_id': 'P-25Y56437062492726MFWZ4GI',
      
'start_time': '2021-10-22T00:00:00Z'

});

But it didnt work

Comment: Don't know what makes you say that. It does work.

Comment: DOH - I had the client ID as test rather than my sandbox client -ID so it wouldn't have been able to find it!!!! Many thanks